# Cannot find "SMB Direct" in Windows Server Standard 2019 Roles and Features

Tags: windows, server-message-block, smbfs, smbclient

I try to configure SMB Direct on my Windows Server Standard 2019 server but do not see "SMB Direct" in the Roles and Features Configuration Window. It, however, shows in my Windows 10 For WorkStation client under "Windows Features". What am I missing?

Comment: did you install an RDMA-capable NIC?

Comment: Are you trying to *add* the feature or to *configure* the feature?  According to the documentation, the only feature that needs to be installed on the server in order to use SMB Direct is the SMB Multichannel feature.

Comment: Mark, are you saying that if no RDMA-capable NIC is detected, the configuration options for SMB Direct will not be shown?  (Also, can you clarify whether there *are* any configuration options for SMB Direct?  The documentation I can find is unclear.)

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-direct

Comment: Yes I use Mellanox ConnectX-4 NICs